# Is there any method available to check whether a string is numeric or not in java?

Tags: java

So I want to check whether my String can be number or not.
I don't want write any boiler plate code for that.
There's one method of **common-apache** `isNumeric()`

But it gives true for `""` blank value and false for decimal values (`12.3`) 
So is there any other method which might do it all ?

Comment: duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Comment: What is `common-apache`? And what exactly do you accept as valid "number" string?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to parse it via a method.

exp.

```
try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(STRING_TO_TEST);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        //do logic 
    }
    return true;
```

But if you dont need this, Apache Commons has a useful method:
exp.

```
NumberUtils.isCreatable("22.6") ;
```

which returns true

```
NumberUtils.isCreatable("") ;
```

which returns false

More info : https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-string-number

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isNumber(String s) {
  try {
    Double.parseDouble(yourString);
    return true;
  } catch(Exception e) {
    return false;
  } 
}
```

This will give you true if Java can resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` for this. The `regex` would be : **`[0-9]+`**

Here are some examples:

```
String regex = "[0-9]+";
System.out.println("12".matches(regex));
System.out.println("abc".matches(regex));
System.out.println("".matches(regex));
```

If you want to consider the decimal values as well, then you can use **`[0-9]+(\.)?[0-9]*`** as regex.

Comment: What about 12.4 or decimal values with other decimal points?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson updated the answer just before this comment was posted.

Comment: And for other locales, what about 12,4 for Sweden?

Comment: That's not specified by OP. If OP wants, I can add.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in apache commons library there exists the NumberUtils class (org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils) having the below given method.

```
 public static boolean isParsable(String str)
```

This checks whether the given String is a parsable number.
Please find the detailed documentation here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isParsable-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

With Apache Commons Lang 3.5 and above: NumberUtils.isCreatable or StringUtils.isNumeric.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-